# in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in line

Tags: php, database, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

In the error log of my server i was getting the following PHP Warning:

in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in " //..." on line 45.

In line 45 i have a function that checks wether WooCommerce plug-in is active.

```
    /**
     * Construction function
     */
    public function __construct() {
        // Check if Woocomerce plugin is actived
        if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
             return;
        }
```

I changed this lines of code after creating a post and replaced it with:

```
if(!is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')) {
    return;
}
```

This then would lead to PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function is_plugin_active() in *** It then proceeded to show me the stack race.

Tried to update it with:

```
if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', (array)apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
   return;
}
```

But Wordpress Theme editor in "class-sober-wc.php" is giving me the eror: Something went wrong. Your change may not have been saved. Please try again. There is also a chance that you may need to manually fix and upload the file over FTP.

Any solutions?

Edit:

```
if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', (array)apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
   return;
}
```

It worked. I couldn´t deploy through the main WP PHP console but after waiting some time i was able to deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Please include plugin.php file before calling is_plugin_active.

```
include_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );

if(!is_plugin_active('woocommerce/woocommerce.php')) { 
    return; 
}
```

When you include plugin.php file it will not throw an error. Because is_plugin_active function placed in the plugin.php file.

**Happy coding**